# How to denote a graph class which allows only $k$ instances of a certain induced subgraph?

Tags: graphs, reference-request, notation

Suppose that a graph class $\mathcal{C}$ is defined as follows:

> A graph $G$ belongs to $\mathcal{C}$ if, and only if $G$ is chordal,
>   but has at most $k$ $5$-cycles.

I am aware that the definition of $\mathcal{C}$ is contradictory. However, I am looking for a notation like

$G \in C_4\text{-free} + k*(C_5)$

Is there such notation in the literature?

Comment: Not a proper answer, but maybe a start: collections of graphs from classes and sets, so set notation is entirely applicable, for example: http://www.graphclasses.org/classes.cgi

Comment: @LukeMathieson That is true, but the set notation has no limitations on the number of instances.